# Why did Animax stop broadcasting "Naruto: Shippuden" in India?

Tags: naruto, india

I don't understand why Animax stopped showing *Naruto: Shippuden* in India. I want to know what happened when Naruto was killed by Sasuke and how exactly he got a son.

Why did Animax stop broadcasting *Naruto: Shippuden* in India?

Comment: Do keep in mind that the Manga finished at chapter 700, the main anime has yet to catch up despite there being a movie set after it

Comment: Yes i know tnat but i was asking about the daily programes not the about manga.

Comment: I don't think there is any official word, it happens to all other anime too, again and again

Comment: `Naruto was killed by Sasuke`? Which episode are you referring to? Naruto has a son with Hinata. But the anime hasn't reached that part.

Comment: its because it was difficult to dub it in HINDI. They have to match the dialogues according to the flaps Which is not easy. Plus after the sasuke retrival arc it was just fillers not the main story line.